# Can I use Vue apps as folders of my Nuxt app website ? If so, how?

Tags: nginx, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vps

I have a Nuxt app hosted on an nginx VPS and two Vue apps besides. I want it that when I go to `nuxtapp.com/folder1` I see one of my Vue app and when I go to `nuxtapp.com/folder2`, I see the other.

Is it possible. If so, how?

Comment: What's the point of the Nuxt app here? Mainly an NGINX matter here.

Comment: @kissu SEO, mostly.

Comment: Vue is still not SSR'ed. Only Nuxt is.